# How to do full-text search in a MySQL table using Fuse.js and Redis?

Tags: javascript, mysql, redis, full-text-search, fuse.js

I have a table with a thousand records in it and I want to do a google like search full-text/fuzzy search.

I read about [MySQL v8's Full-Text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and let's say we don't have that functionality yet.

There is this JavaScript library called [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) that do fuzzy-search which is what I need.

I can combine it by creating a API that returns the table data in JSON format and then pass it to Fuse.js to do a fuzzy-search.

Now, I think it's not recommended to load all data from table every time someone wants to search.

I read about Redis, and the first thing that came in my mind is to save all table data in Redis using `JSON.stringify` and just call it every time instead of querying the database. Then whenever a data is added in the table, I will also update the contents of the data in Redis.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very common caching pattern.

If you need a more efficient way to store and retrieve your JSON to/from Redis you might want to consider one of the available Redis Modules.

e.g.

[RedisJSON](http://redisjson.io) allows you to efficiently store, retrieve, project (jsonpath) and update in place.

[RediSearch](http://redisearch.io) allows you to have full text search over Redis Hash and efficiently retrieve data according to the user's query.

Last

[RedisJSON2 (aka RedisDoc)](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisDoc/) combines both modules above, meaning efficient JSON store and retrieve with Full Text support